# Best aproach when dealing with mutliple promisses

Tags: angularjs, callback, directive

I was looking on the internet but did not see a definitive answer. So here is my case:

The code is written by head so excuse for not being complete
I have a page that looks something like:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <my-customer my-callback="directiveCallback(item)" />
</div>
```

I then have a script that looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'apiService', function($scope, apiService) {

    apiResponse = apiService.getAll('myRepo');

    apiResponse.then(function(d){
     $scope.data = d;   
    })

    $scope.directiveCallback = function(item) {

        // do stuff with $scope.data
    }

  }])
  .directive('myCustomer', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            myCallback:'&'
        },
      template: 'Name: {{customer.name}} Address: {{customer.address}}'
    };
  });
```

The thing is the service promise resolves and returns some data.
The directive controller is calling another service that returns some data and fires the call back when it is done with the data that it recives.

When he lands on the callback function the item is attached to the $scope.data.

The problem was that the callback is triggered before $scope.data is populated.
I curently salved this so that I wraped the callback in a $timeout with a settable delay via a direcitve parameter.

Is that is correct way to do it or is there a better way?

Comment: You already have a promise. You can chain it inside directiveCallback, can't you?

Comment: you mean to pass it to the direcitveCallback?

Comment: Or to use the apiResponse in the direcitve callback?

Comment: 1. Have the service cache and return the same **promise**. 2 Inject the service into any dependencies (like component, controllers, and directives). 3. Each dependency can call the method(s) required and the service and do something with the resulting promise.

Comment: What not to do is pass around call backs, that is a bad design where you will be creating tightly coupled components (*general term, not angularjs components although they would also apply to that category*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, doesnt this simply work:

```
$scope.directiveCallback = function(item) {
  apiResponse.then(function() {
    console.log($scope.data); // always updated
    // do whatever
  })
}
```